# Count visible drop down options in opera and chrome, hide select option in IE

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox, opera

I have drop down list and button. When I click on button I want to hide selected option and when there is no more available options - hide select itself. Pretty simple **BUT**... This code (see below and on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RKK2V/) ) doesn't work with opera and chrome but perfectly works in mozilla. By doesn't work I mean that visible option length is always 0. So how can I count visible select options in those browsers? Few words about IE: `selectedOption.hide();` and other hide methods like `selectedOption.display('none');` and `selectedOption.style('display', 'none');` do not actually hide the option... How do I do that in IE?

```
<input type="button" value="Ckick" id="hide-option-button" />

<select id="my-select">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>    
</select>


$(document).ready(function(){

var button = $('#hide-option-button');
var dropDown = $('#my-select');

button.click(function(){
    var selectedOption = dropDown.find('option:selected');

    // Do nothing if empty option selected
    if (selectedOption.val() == '') return;

    // Remove selected option from drop down (just hide it to be able display it again after)
    selectedOption.hide();

    // Select first empty item to prevent glitch with displaying just selected and hided option in drop down
    dropDown.val('');

    if(shouldHideDropDown(dropDown))
    {
        dropDown.hide();
    }
});

function shouldHideDropDown(dropDown) {
    var visibleOptions = dropDown.children(':visible');
    console.log(visibleOptions.length);
    console.log(visibleOptions.size());
    return visibleOptions.length === 1;
}

});
```

P.S. I use Opera **17.0.1241.53**, Chrome **30.0.1599.101 m**, Mozilla Firefox **24.0**, IE **10.0.920016721** running on **Windows 7 x64**.

Answer (score 0):

I went through bad times when trying to apply css style on html option elements (trying to do exactly the same you are doing).

I tried to use `display:none`, `opacity:0` and even replacing it's value to empty.

After you hide an option, focus your select box and start using the keyboard. You will see that even when the option is hidden, **the option will be displayed!**.

I had to modify all my code to get this working. I solve this problem by NOT trying to style html options elements and starting using another approch (javascript aux arrays).

Answer (score 0):

This is  bug in  chrome. I hope they resolve soon.